# how can call a asmx webservice by parsing an object as parameter,

Tags: php, yii

Here is my code

```
$objLogParameter = new LogParameters();
$objLogParameter->strLogMessage = $message."&nbsp".$extendedMessage;
$objLogParameter->strStackTrace = $preStackTrace;
$objLogParameter->strUser = "Osmosys";
$objLogParameter->strCustomer = "ws";
$objLogParameter->strPageOrModuleName = "calling ws";
$objLogParameter->strApplication = "OsmTest";
$objLogParameter->strSubscription = "test2";
$objLogParameter->EnumSeverity = "Error";
$objLogParameter->EnumLogType = "ErrorTest";
$url    = "http://log.cocoonit.in/writelogsindbservice.asmx?WSDL"; 
$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1));
$res = $client->WriteLogInDB($objLogParameter);
```

`WriteLogInDB` is a method in .asmx webservice, thats method except an object as a argument then if i pass a object in $res i got a msg  like status code = 0,object couldn't be empty.

I want to connect this Url 
http://log.cocoonit.in/writelogsindbservice.asmx
and in this it have a WriteLogInDB method, i want to call this method by passing an object nothing but $objLogParameter. how can i do it in php. 
Please help me.

Comment: what is not working ?? what is the error/response you are getting ?

Comment: In $res i got an associate array WriteLogInDBResult => Object, in that object we have a msg with object can not be null